# How to make a flask website that generates dynamic google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api, xlsxwriter, google-sheets-formula

I'm helping an organization out and they wish to have a website in which you input some numbers and a Google Sheets link should appear in which the numbers are put into some formula to give a result (i.e if you put in `5, 5, 3; (Num1 + Num2) * num3` it'd show a table in which the first two numbers are added then multiplied by the third:

```
Num1    Num2     Num2  Result
5       5        3     30
```

I have searched GitHub and the internet but I cannot seem to find a library that can **create** a Google Sheet from a website with given data input into a formula. Most stuff I found used the gsheet API and only modified an existing sheet. I found a Python (Flask) library called [xlsxwriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io) and I was wondering if there is any way to convert an `.xlsx` to an online Google Sheet or if possible to just make a Google Sheet from my website.

(My website is in Flask as of right now but since I literally have no backend. If someone knows of a library that is in another web framework, I am willing to switch.)

Thank you, John D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I am missing something here but the regular Google Sheets API (which is available for Python) allows you to create blank spreadsheets with a specified title.

```
spreadsheet = {
    'properties': {
        'title': title
    }
}
spreadsheet = service.spreadsheets().create(body=spreadsheet,
                                    fields='spreadsheetId').execute()
print('Spreadsheet ID: {0}'.format(spreadsheet.get('spreadsheetId')))
```

- https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/create
- https://github.com/gsuitedevs/python-samples/blob/master/sheets/snippets/spreadsheet_snippets.py
- https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python

Here is a more complete sample based on the Google Quickstarts examples:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pickle
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle! Adjust scopes as needed
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']


def main():
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)

    # Call the Sheets API

    spreadsheet = {
        'properties': {
            'title': 'New Test Sheet 2'
        }
    }
    spreadsheet = service.spreadsheets().create(body=spreadsheet,
                                        fields='spreadsheetId').execute()
    #print('Spreadsheet ID: {0}'.format(spreadsheet.get('spreadsheetId')))
    spreadsheet_id = spreadsheet.get('spreadsheetId')

    range_name = 'Sheet1!A1:D5'
    body = {
        "majorDimension": "ROWS",
        "values": [
            ["Item", "Cost", "Stocked", "Ship Date"],
            ["Wheel", "$20.50", "4", "3/1/2016"],  # new row
            ["Door", "$15", "2", "3/15/2016"],
            ["Engine", "$100", "1", "30/20/2016"],
            ["Totals", "=SUM(B2:B4)", "=SUM(C2:C4)", "=MAX(D2:D4)"]
        ],
    }
    result = service.spreadsheets().values().update(
        spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id,
        range=range_name,
        body=body,
        valueInputOption='USER_ENTERED'
    ).execute()
    print(result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```